# Streaming Video in VLC using UDP

Tags: udp, video-streaming, vlc, live-streaming

I need to stream video in vlc through udp. I am transmitting video from one network and my  receiving pc will be in some another network. Can anyone help, how can i specify Host name (Address) for transmitting stream so that, my pc can use same to receive the stream using udp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check if you are able to reach (ping) to receiver from sender? If yes, you can use UDP. Else do the route configuration into sender PC / router. On an alternate note if you can reach to sender pc from receiver pc, you can stream over http in vlc.